# Register page wont insert data to database

Tags: php

Not sure why but when I hit submit on register form it wont insert data into database, it performs the last else statement at the bottom by redirecting to signup success page which confuses me. I had it working but I did something and I cant figure out what is wrong..

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $password = md5($_POST['password']);
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $Fname = $_POST['Fname'];
     $Lname = $_POST['Lname'];
     $Display1 = $_POST['Display1'];
     $Display2 = $_POST['Display2'];
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username'");
     if(empty($username) or empty($password) or empty($email) or  empty($Fname) or empty($Lname) or empty($Display1)) {
        echo '<p>Fields Empty!</p>';
     } else if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
         $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username   ='$username' AND password ='$password'");
         echo'<p>Username or Password Already Exists!</p>';
     } else {
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$username', '$password', '2', 'a', '$Fname', '$Lname', '$email', '$Display1', '$Display2')");

         $subject = "Membership Confirmation";
         $message = "Hello, You have registered an account on Joepepjoepep.com";
         $from = "From: joepep235@gmail.com";

         header("location:signuppayment.php");
         mail($email, $subject, $message, $from);
     }
}
?>
```

Comment: What does it say, is error reporting on?  You are open to SQL injections with this code. Also this doesn't appear to be being used `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username   ='$username' AND password ='$password'");`

Comment: do you have any error in your php error logs?

Comment: its not giving me any errors at all which is confusing me even more.

Comment: Is it configured to give you errors?

Comment: Have you checked in mysql whether the data is inserted there

Comment: yes i checked in mysql many times, it doesnt show up and yes it should give me errors, but as far I can tell there is nothing wrong with my code?

Comment: Use this query, `mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL, '$username', '$password', '2', 'a', '$Fname', '$Lname', '$email', '$Display1', '$Display2')");
`

Comment: didnt work @MansoorH

Comment: have to tried using || this instead of or ?

Comment: yea i did @aizele  found out what i did and reverted back to it seems i solved the problem       `mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(id, username, password, Display1, Display2, email, Fname, Lname, user_level, type) VALUES ('', '$username', '$password', '$Display1', '$Display2', '$email', '$Fname', '$Lname', '2', 'a')");`

Comment: so did I answer your question?

Comment: @aizele not really but it was all useful for me to realize my mistake so thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Create a [unique key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html) for your username field in the table definition.
Then a username can only be once in the table and a second insert query with the same username will fail with a [specific error code](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_key). (and you avoid the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) because of your multiple queries)
You can check for that error code and then display the "username already in use" error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
 You forgot to put the rows you need to be inserted in your database.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('', '$username', '$password', '2', 'a', '$Fname', '$Lname', '$email', '$Display1', '$Display2')");
```

Change this into something like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(id, username, password, Display1, Display2, email, Fname, Lname, user_level, type) VALUES ('', '$username', '$password', '$Display1', '$Display2', '$email', '$Fname', '$Lname', '2', 'a')");
```

and so apply this in your code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $Fname = $_POST['Fname'];
    $Lname = $_POST['Lname'];
    $Display1 = $_POST['Display1'];
    $Display2 = $_POST['Display2'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username'");
     if((empty($username)) || (empty($password)) || (empty($email)) ||  (empty($Fname)) || (empty($Lname)) || (empty($Display1))) {
        echo '<p>Fields Empty!</p>';
     } else if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
         $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username   ='$username' AND password ='$password'");
         echo'<p>Username or Password Already Exists!</p>';
     } else {
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(id, username, password, Display1, Display2, email, Fname, Lname, user_level, type) VALUES ('', '$username', '$password', '$Display1', '$Display2', '$email', '$Fname', '$Lname', '2', 'a')");

            $subject = "Membership Confirmation";
            $message = "Hello, You have registered an account on Joepepjoepep.com";
            $from = "From: joepep235@gmail.com";

            header("location:signuppayment.php");
            mail($email, $subject, $message, $from);
 }

 }

 ?>
```

Hope this helps.